# Mutable Hastable : Illegal type synonym family application in instance

Tags: haskell, hashtable, type-families, type-synonyms

I'm trying to use Mutable BasicHashTable from this lib : https://github.com/gregorycollins/hashtables

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import qualified Data.HashTable.IO as H
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO)

type A  =  H.BasicHashTable Int String

newtype MyWrapper a = MyWrapper { runM :: StateT A IO a  }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadState A )
```

The compiler is complaining on my attempts to use `A` in a typeclass instance:

```
 error:
    • Illegal type synonym family application ‘Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState
                                                 IO’ in instance:
        MonadState A MyWrapper
    • In the newtype declaration for ‘MyWrapper’
   |
10 |   deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadState A )
   |                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: looking at  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360959/illegal-type-synonym-family-application-in-instance-with-functional-dependency

Comment: I think it freaks out PrimState about the type family: Try this:
import qualified Data.HashTable.ST.Basic       as B
type A  =  B.HashTable Int String RealWorld

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it freaks out because `PrimState` is a type family. Try this:

```hs
import Control.Monad.ST (RealWorld)
import qualified Data.HashTable.ST.Basic as B
type A = B.HashTable Int String RealWorld
```

The compilation error you get tells us that it can't handle the type family. If you look at definition of hash table type you'll find the `PrimState` usage it complains about:

```hs
import qualified Data.HashTable.ST.Basic as B
type BasicHashTable k v = IOHashTable (B.HashTable) k v
type IOHashTable tabletype k v = tabletype (PrimState IO) k v
```

Therefore you can use it directly yourself, [because](https://github.com/haskell/primitive/blob/87b50ced840b3b1adbd61fe709b2e042f06e6ff3/Control/Monad/Primitive.hs#L97):

```hs
type instance PrimState IO = RealWorld
```

In fact. I'd even submit a PR upstream with a fix:

```
- type IOHashTable tabletype k v = tabletype (PrimState IO) k v
+ type IOHashTable tabletype k v = tabletype RealWorld k v
```

because there is no good reason to have it defined in the way it is now